# Не удается открыть файл C

Tags: c

Задание написать на C игру жизнь. Функция `init_grille_from_file` уже была дана. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии q происходил выход из игры (работает), при нажатии n считывалось имя нового файла, откуда происходит инициализация "сетки" игры.

Код для нажатия клавиши n:

```
    case 'n' : 
    {
        char* filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        printf("Entrez le nom d'une nouvelle grille : ");         //введите имя файла
        getchar();                                                
        fgets(filename, 100, stdin);                              // считывание строки
        filename = (char*)realloc(filename, strlen(filename)-1);  // смена размера filename
        init_grille_from_file(filename,g); ...                       // функция читающая файл
```

Функция `init_grille_from_file`:

```
void init_grille_from_file (char * filename, grille* g){
FILE * pfile = NULL;
pfile = fopen(filename, "r");
 /*if( access( filename, F_OK ) != -1 ) {                 // выводит no - файл не существует
    printf("yes");
} else {
printf("no");
}*/
assert (pfile != NULL);
...
```

main :

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage : main <fichier grille>");
        return 1;
    }
    grille g, gc;
    init_grille_from_file(argv[1],&g);...
```

Использование :

```
agmarie1315 ~/Desktop/Учеба/S3L2/Technique de developp/jeu_vie_MA $ ./main grille4.txt

|

n
Entrez le nom d'une nouvelle grille : grille4.txt
Assertion failed: (pfile != NULL), function init_grille_from_file, file src/grille.c, line 23.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, функция `fgets` читает в строку-получатель и символ перевода строки `\n`, который вам следует удалить пред тем, как использовать эту строку в качестве имени файла

```
filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Во-вторых, что это за ужас

```
filename = (char*)realloc(filename, strlen(filename)-1);
```

?

Здесь вы зачем-то "откусываете" у строки финальный `\0`. Ваша строка больше не является строкой. Дальнейшее поведение не определено.

Если уж вы хотите освободить "лишнюю" память (но зачем?), то тогда уж надо было делать

```
filename = realloc(filename, strlen(filename) + 1);
```

`+1`, а не `-1`. Разумеется, если делать это таким образом, то только после предыдущего шага.

Мне, однако, не ясно, зачем вы вообще выделяли эту память через `malloc` вместо того, чтобы просто объявить локальный массив.